# Using a Scanner to solicit a file name JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to open whose name is written into the console. I can't seem to resolve the type mismatch. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Scanner inputFileName = new Scanner(System.in);
File file = new File (inputFileName);
```

Comment: You have to actually get the user input... you can't just pass a Scanner to the constructor of File

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: You are trying to create a File object with a Scanner object. Use inputFileName.nextLine() to get input from the keyboard. That method will return a String which you can pass to the File constructor. For example. String fileName = inputFileName.nextLine(); File file = new File(fileName);

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this: `String name = inputFileName.nextLine()`. So when you call `nextLine()` you are reading the rest of this first line.

In your code, you are not getting any input from the user.

You'll find more information on their implementation in the [API Documentation for java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, your `inputFileName` is only a `Scanner` object which you can use it to prompt for user input. It is ***not*** your filename nor is it prompting for any input at the moment.

You may use `inputFileName.nextLine()` to prompt user for input first:

```
Scanner inputFileName = new Scanner(System.in);  //Create Scanner object 
String fileName = inputFileName.nextLine();      //Store user's input in fileName
File file = new File (fileName);                 //Create File object with fileName
```